# .split() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that i transformed it into text with array-to-txt module.

Instead i wanted it transformed to a big string, but i wanted a newline after every index of the array (the afforementioned module does this automatically).

So i wrote this:

```
result.toString();
result = result.split(",").join("\n");
```

Where result is the array. It didn't work, so then i tried this:

```
result.toString();
var output = result.split(",").join("\n");
```

Still i get the `TypeError: result.split is not a function` error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you have is `result.toString()` doesn't modify the original array...it only ***returns*** a string.

You would need something like:

```
var str = result.toString()
var output= str.split(',').join('\n');
```

However there is no need to convert to string and immediately back to array when all you really need is:

```
var output = result.join('\n')
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498699/error-typeerror-text-split-is-not-a-function-in-text-split-s-text-sp

Answer (score 2):

to convert the array into string use var k = String(result);
var outPut = k.split(',').join('\n');

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = ['a','b','c'];

const data = result.join('\n');

console.log(data);
```