# ERROR TypeError: text.split is not a function. (In 'text.split(/\s+/)', 'text.split' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

**App.js**

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

const handleOnChange = (text) => {
  setText(text)
}

<View style={styles.textarea}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter Your text here!!"
              placeholderTextColor={'#666161'}
              textAlignVertical="top"
              value={text}
              multiline={true}
              onChange={(text)=>handleOnChange(text)}
              style={{
                padding: 15,
                width:windowWidth/1.10,
                height: verticalScale(350),
                borderColor: '#fff',
                backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: scale(10),
                fontSize: RFPercentage(3),
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              }}
            />
          </View>
           <Text style={styles.textsummy}>{text.split(/\s+/).filter((element) => { return element.length !== 0 }).length} <Text style={{color:'#E5E5E5',fontWeight:'normal'}}>words and</Text> {text.length} <Text style={{color:'#E5E5E5',fontWeight:'normal'}}>characters</Text></Text>
```

**Error:**

```
 ERROR  TypeError: text.split is not a function. (In 'text.split(/\s+/)', 'text.split' is undefined)
```

In my project, one textarea and textarea value are stored in `text` the state and I will apply the split function in `text` the state

because it will count as a word or character if the textarea is null then the word is **0** or if you type one word and press enter then the word is **1,** not a two in sort it only counts the word, not a blank space.

but whenever I try to run my project and type something on textarea view it's given me an error as given above.

anyone can tell me where I do a mistake

Comment: did you log the text variable to see the result ? you can use **text?.split()** to prevent errors

Comment: Try using `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`.

Comment: Yesh it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in two ways :

**Method 1 :**  **Using onChnageText:**

```
onChangeText={(text)=>handleOnChange(text)}
```

**Method 2 : Using OnChange :**

```
onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event.nativeEvent.text)}
```